# I can't publish my shinyapp, any advice to solve this error

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I am trying to develop a Shinyapp for modeling the COVID-19 illness, but I can't find the error when I try to publish it. In R, the code is running OK and everything is correctly shown, but when I try to publish, an error is shown in the part where the plot should be: "An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification." 
I'm trying to use Prophet package. I'm new with this package and this is my first app, so I will appreciate your help...

The logs:

```
2020-04-04T06:19:59.741057+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]: Disabling daily seasonality. Run prophet with daily.seasonality=TRUE to override this.
2020-04-04T06:19:59.794156+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]: Compiling model (this will take a few minutes...)
2020-04-04T06:19:59.794607+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]: If this is the first time fitting a model since package install, this is normal. You should not see this message more than once after install.
2020-04-04T06:19:59.795419+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]: Writing model to: /opt/R/3.6.3/lib/R/library/prophet/libs
2020-04-04T06:19:59.795868+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]: Compiling using binary: /opt/R/3.6.3/lib/R/bin
2020-04-04T06:20:26.545815+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]: Warning in system(cmd, intern = !verbose) :
2020-04-04T06:20:26.545817+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   comando ejecutado '/opt/R/3.6.3/lib/R/bin/R CMD SHLIB file10a8c62e87.cpp 2> file10a8c62e87.cpp.err.txt' tiene estatus 1
2020-04-04T06:20:26.602133+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]: Warning: Error in sink: conexión inválida
2020-04-04T06:20:26.610392+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   185: sink
2020-04-04T06:20:26.610394+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   184: cxxfunctionplus
2020-04-04T06:20:26.610395+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   182: compile_stan_model
2020-04-04T06:20:26.610394+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   183: rstan::stan_model
2020-04-04T06:20:26.610395+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   181: fit.prophet
2020-04-04T06:20:26.610396+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   179: renderPlot [/srv/connect/apps/COVID19-Mexico/app.R#131]
2020-04-04T06:20:26.610396+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   177: fund
2020-04-04T06:20:26.610419+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   137: drawPlot
2020-04-04T06:20:26.610420+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   123: <reactive:plotObj>
2020-04-04T06:20:26.610420+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   107: drawReactive
2020-04-04T06:20:26.610421+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:    94: origRenderFunc
2020-04-04T06:20:26.610421+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:    93: output$timeplot
2020-04-04T06:20:26.610421+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:    13: runApp
2020-04-04T06:20:26.610422+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:     6: eval
2020-04-04T06:20:26.610422+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:    12: fn
2020-04-04T06:20:26.610423+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:     5: eval
2020-04-04T06:20:26.771701+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]: Disabling yearly seasonality. Run prophet with yearly.seasonality=TRUE to override this.
2020-04-04T06:20:26.610395+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   180: prophet
2020-04-04T06:20:26.610422+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:     7: connect$retry
2020-04-04T06:20:26.772159+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]: Disabling daily seasonality. Run prophet with daily.seasonality=TRUE to override this.
2020-04-04T06:20:26.883191+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]: Compiling model (this will take a few minutes...)
2020-04-04T06:20:26.883501+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]: If this is the first time fitting a model since package install, this is normal. You should not see this message more than once after install.
2020-04-04T06:20:26.884052+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]: Writing model to: /opt/R/3.6.3/lib/R/library/prophet/libs
2020-04-04T06:20:26.884384+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]: Compiling using binary: /opt/R/3.6.3/lib/R/bin
2020-04-04T06:20:56.818503+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]: Warning in system(cmd, intern = !verbose) :
2020-04-04T06:20:56.818505+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   comando ejecutado '/opt/R/3.6.3/lib/R/bin/R CMD SHLIB file10a4e80f688.cpp 2> file10a4e80f688.cpp.err.txt' tiene estatus 1
2020-04-04T06:20:56.867650+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]: Warning: Error in sink: conexión inválida
2020-04-04T06:20:56.872694+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   115: sink
2020-04-04T06:20:56.872694+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   114: cxxfunctionplus
2020-04-04T06:20:56.872695+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   113: rstan::stan_model
2020-04-04T06:20:56.872695+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   112: compile_stan_model
2020-04-04T06:20:56.872695+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   111: fit.prophet
2020-04-04T06:20:56.872696+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   110: prophet
2020-04-04T06:20:56.872696+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   109: compute_data [/srv/connect/apps/COVID19-Mexico/app.R#221]
2020-04-04T06:20:56.872697+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   108: renderTable [/srv/connect/apps/COVID19-    Mexico/app.R#272]
2020-04-04T06:20:56.872707+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:   107: fund
2020-04-04T06:20:56.872707+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:    94: origRenderFunc
2020-04-04T06:20:56.872707+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:    93: output$table
2020-04-04T06:20:56.872708+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:    13: runApp
2020-04-04T06:20:56.872708+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:    12: fn
2020-04-04T06:20:56.872709+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:     7: connect$retry
2020-04-04T06:20:56.872709+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:     6: eval
2020-04-04T06:20:56.872709+00:00 shinyapps[2055422]:     5: eval
```

Any advice or another way to publish this app? Thanks
download the [script](https://mega.nz/file/jkhU0KZZ#QzgxKDVArc9uIdTk9Usfzl5RLrzpULDqC441ci9RF0I)

> Blockquote

Comment: post the code of your app here plz so we can reproduce

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the package, from prophet to forecast, and plotting with Plotly.

Comment: you should post the answer and accept as so others can reference it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the package, from prophet to forecast, and plotting with Plotly. I think that the problem was the dyplot.prophet, but with Plotly and Forecast packages the problem was solved. I used the plotly code from [here](https://plotly.com/r/graphing-multiple-chart-types/)

```
    ts_cases = ts(mex$y,ts(mex$y, start=min(mex$ds), end = max(mex$ds), frequency=1))

    fit <- auto.arima(ts_cases)
    f_arima<- forecast(fit, 20) # forecast

    # names
    f <- list(
      family = "Arial",
      size = 18,
      color = "#7f7f7f"
    )
    x <- list(
      title = "Tiempo en dias",
      titlefont = f
    )
    y <- list(
      title = "Numero de casos confirmados",
      titlefont = f
    )

    library(plotly)
    plot_ly() %>%
      add_lines(x = time(ts_cases), y = ts_cases,hoverinfo = "text",
                color = I("black"), name = "observed") %>%
      add_ribbons(x = time(f_arima$mean), ymin = f_arima$lower[, 2], ymax = f_arima$upper[, 2],
                  color = I("gray95"), name = "95% confidence") %>%
      add_ribbons(x = time(f_arima$mean), ymin = f_arima$lower[, 1], ymax = f_arima$upper[, 1],
                  color = I("gray80"), name = "80% confidence") %>%
      add_lines(x = time(f_arima$mean), y = f_arima$mean, color = I("blue"), name = "prediction")%>% layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y,title= "ARIMA model")
```